# Prolog display the results in an array/list

Tags: prolog

So I've this problem that is bugging me a lot:

We've the fact `student(sID,LR,[courses]).`

In which `sID` is the student ID, `LR` to determine if he is a left or right-handed person, and `[courses]` is an array of courses.

Next, we've the predicate `listStudents(C,L)` which `C` represents one Course and `L` the List. The predicate wants to return a List of Students that are in `C` Course.

Example:

```
student(23,1,[math101,phy203]).
student(24,0,[math101,phy203,art]).
student(25,1,[phy203,art]).

?- listStudents(math101,L)
L=[23,24]
```

Now, I've tried for several things like:

```
listStudents(C,L):- student(C,_,Y), member(C,Y)
```

and I realized later it's wrong as it returns me

```
L=23
L=24
```

Afterwards I was reading about findall() and made this

```
listStudents(C,L):- findall(S, study(C,S), L).
study(C,S):- estudiante(S,_,Y), member(C,Y).
```

which makes a return that I did not expect

```
L=[23,23,24,24,24]
```

Comment: Your code works as is (replacing `estudiante` with `student`) with the database provided. Have you modified your database so that you have duplicates? Also, you can do it in one predicate with `findall(S, (student(S,_,C), member(math101, C)), Students).`.

Comment: Oh my, I didn't know that you could that with findall(), including those parentheses made the difference. Thank you! By the way, sorry for the typo as I was programming in Spanish

Comment: Yes, whenever the docs say ":Goal", you can put a parenthesized sequence of arbitrary Prolog in there. :)